# IncludeFilter in EntityFramework CORE-Plus not filtering the included record

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1, entity-framework-plus

Using the below Linq query with Entity Framework Core 3 and the EntityFramework Core Plus library I would expect that I would return 1 Factor with all the Items with the IsActive boolean set to true. Instead what I get is the 1 Factor and all Items whether the IsActive value is true or false.
Why?

```
public class Factor 
    {
        public Factor()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>();
        }
        public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
        public int FactorId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Item 
    {
        [ForeignKey("Factor")]
        public int? FactorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Factor Factor { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

    }
```

```
Factors
.IncludeFilter(a => a.Items.Where(b => b.IsActive))
.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.FactorId == 1140)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: The code you have added is not complete. However, when I use the classes and build it in a workable environment and run it, it works as it should. The library will generate a query like this: https://pastebin.com/hC3sskFP. As you see the query is generated correctly. It is most likely a context issue where you have the items you don't want already in the context and EF will add them to the collections anyway, but it is difficult to say without a MCVE. Please add one to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This part doesn't look valid:

```
.IncludeFilter(a => a.Items.Where(a => a.IsActive))
```

You use twice "a" which cannot compile.

Perhaps by mistake, you are currently checking if the Factor is currently `IsActive` instead of all your items.

Comment: I tried changing the query as reflected above and it still returns all IsActive (whether true or false)

Comment: In this case John, report it here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues with a runnable project that reproduces the issue

Comment: hi Jon, I have a question here also, maybe you can answer, thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461990/c-sharp-entity-framework-bulk-updatefromquery-in-batches